# PHP error: "The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping."

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run a `composer update` I get this error message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Failed to download psr/log from dist: The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    Now trying to download from source
```

What do I need to do to enable the zip and unzip commands so that composer can download dependencies?

Comment: Workaround: Use 

`composer update --prefer-source`


I had this issue when trying to `composer update` phpspec.

`Failed to download symfony/polyfill-ctype from dist: The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping.`

I am on a Mac and had problems making Homebrew work to install php extensions. 

So, my quick fix was to force `composer` _not_ to need to use zip by adding the --prefer-source option. This means it downloads the repo instead of a zipped package. 

Not a long term solution but handy to know.

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Depending on your flavour of Linux and PHP version these may vary.

```
(sudo) yum install zip unzip php-zip
(sudo) apt install zip unzip php-zip
```

This is a very commonly asked question, you'll be able to find more useful info in the aether by searching `<distro> php <version> zip extension`.

Comment: For Ubuntu `apt-get install php-zip` is sufficient

Comment: @OlafDietsche How do you know/determine when to install `php[version]-package` vs `php-package` for any given package? Would love to know as I usually just go with the `php[version]-package` version, but perhaps that's not optimal…

Comment: @elbowlobstercowstand `php-<package>` is the default version. These packages just depend on the most recent version. If you need some specific (usually older) version, you install `php<version>-<package>`.

Comment: It also works for `# yum install zip unzip php7.2-zip` (on CentOS 7)

Comment: People keep giving instructions to install php-zip as well as zip/unzip. It makes no sense that it needs both.

Comment: people using docker (nov '19) use : RUN apt-get install  -y zlib1g-dev \
     && docker-php-ext-install zip

Comment: I found that @naman1994's proposal is missing `libzip-dev` for dockerfiles `from php:7.3`. So it should be `RUN … apt-get install -yqq … zlib1g-dev libzip-dev && docker-php-ext-install zip`

Comment: Also, you really should install unzip. Otherwise composer will complain: `As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension. This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Besides, any UNIX permissions (e.g. executable) defined in the archives will be lost. Installing 'unzip' may remediate them.` So it should be `RUN … apt-get install -yqq … zlib1g-dev libzip-dev unzip && docker-php-ext-install zip`

Answer (score 106):

For Windows, in case you're using a locale development environment like XAMPP, just locate the php.ini file (C:\xampp\php in my case), open it and remove the semicolon from the following line.

```
;extension=zip
```

Restart your Apache webserver and it will work fine.

Comment: good job
My work really started
I just asked chatgpt and he gave really funny answers

Comment: it save my time, working in my windows pc

Comment: Works for me in development with xampp, php version 8.1 and Laravel version 10.8

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked out for me like charm.

Comment: Work for me thanks !

Comment: Works with xampp, PHP version  8.2.12 and Laravel Framework 10.43.0
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 53):

Not to belabor the point, but if you are working in a `Dockerfile`, you would solve this particular issue with Composer by installing the `unzip` utility.  Below is an example using the [official PHP image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) to install `unzip` and the `zip` PHP extension for good measure.

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Install unzip utility and libs needed by zip PHP extension 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
```

[This is a helpful GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/61) where the above is lovingly lifted from.

Comment: I enjoyed your prose in this answer. Thank you

Comment: In my case, doing apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev libzip-dev unzip gets the error gone.

Comment: If warning comes from composer executed in php:7.4-cli with Dockerfile, by installing just `zip` warning goes away. `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip`. It didn't request for unzip, libs nor docker-php-ext...

Answer (score 52):

For servers with PHP 5.6

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php5.6-zip
```

Comment: You are a life saver, my friend.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: sudo apt-get install zip unzip php7.4-zip // according to your PHP version

Answer (score 26):

For Debian Jessie (which is the current default for the PHP image on Docker Hub):

```
apt-get install --yes zip unzip php-pclzip
```

You can omit the --yes, but it's useful when you're RUN-ing it in a Dockerfile.

Comment: thanks for sharing Peter, saved me some time looking for the right version of `php-zip` :D

Answer (score 24):

For older Ubuntu distros i.e 16.04, 14.04, 12.04 etc

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php7.0-zip
```

Comment: including 16.04

Answer (score 17):

Please check your composer status first

```
composer diagnose
```

If the status showing

```
zip: extension not found, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available
```

then

1. Open your XAMPP Server
2. Apache -> config button ->Click "PHP(php.ini)"
3. Find "zip"
4. ";extension = zip will shown
5. Remove the semicolon and save the file
6. Restart your XAMPP Apache

Now

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <<project_name>>
```

or

```
laravel new <<project_name>>
```

Answer (score 16):

I had PHP7.2 on a Ubuntu 16.04 server and it solved my problem:

`sudo apt-get install zip unzip php-zip`

**Update**

Tried this for Ubuntu 18.04 and worked as well.

Answer (score 10):

I'm Using Ubuntu and with the following command worked

`apt-get install --yes zip unzip`

Answer (score 8):

For Windows Users:

Locate your php.ini  and open it with a text editor.

Search for 'zip'. If you're using PHP 8.2, you'd probably find it on line 952 written like this:
;extension=zip

Remove the ';' so it looks like this->
extension =zip
Save and you're good to go!

Answer (score 7):

For PHP8.2 (Windows)

As stated here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php#zip.installation.new.windows

> As of PHP 8.2.0, php_zip.dll DLL must be enabled in php.ini. Previously, this extension was built-in.

You will need to manually enable this extension within your php.ini by adding `extension=php_zip.dll`

For a list of installed extensions you can run:

```
php -m
```

or if you have `grep` installed even easier would be:

```
php -m | grep "zip"
```

Answer (score 5):

On docker with image `php:7.2-apache` I just needed zip and unzip. No need for php-zip :

`apt-get install zip unzip`

or Dockerfile

```
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "zip"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "unzip"]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Ubuntu and PHP 7.2**, use this...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I installed Laravel 5.5 on my digitalocean cloud server (Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.2) and the following command fixed it.

> `sudo apt install zip unzip php7.2-zip`

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 8.2.0, php_zip.dll DLL **must be enabled in php.ini**. Previously, this extension was built-in.

you can do that:

edit **php.ini** file and **remove** semicolon in the line

```
;extension=zip
```

**save** the file and you good to go..

Answer (score 3):

Actually composer nowadays seems to work without the `zip` command line command, so  installing `php-zip` should be enough --- BUT it would display a warning:

> As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the 
>   PHP zip extension.
>   This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Installing 'unzip' may
>   remediate them.

See also [Is there a problem with using php-zip (composer warns about it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52444600/is-there-a-problem-with-using-php-zip-composer-warns-about-it)

Answer (score 3):

`PHP-ZIP` needs some dependancies or library missing, depends on the image from `Dockerfile` you need to install them first

```
RUN set -eux \
   && apt-get update \
   && apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev \
   && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP **8.1**

```sh
apt-get install --yes zip
```

Answer (score 3):

After run

```
apt install php-zip
```

and run again

```
composer require ...
```

I get the next warning and suggestion

As there is no 'unzip' nor '7z' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.

This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Besides, any UNIX permissions (e.g. executable) defined in the archives will be lost.

Installing 'unzip' or '7z' (21.01+) may remediate them.

As there is no 'unzip' nor '7z' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.

This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Besides, any UNIX permissions (e.g. executable) defined in the archives will be lost.

Installing 'unzip' or '7z' (21.01+) may remediate them.

So I suggest install unzip first.

```
apt install unzip
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest command to fix it on **Debian** and **Ubuntu** (dependencies will be installed automatically):

```
sudo apt install php-zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for PHP 7.4:

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php7.4-zip
```

And for PHP 8.0:

```
sudo apt-get install zip unzip php8.0-zip
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using XAMPP to run your php code in the latest release, zip extensions are commented out you have to activate them yourself. Navigate to C:\xampp\php, open the php.ini file and find the commented line and uncomment as follows by removing starting semicolon

```
;extension=zip
```

to

```
extension=zip
```

save and rerun you command. works like magic!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error in my Windows system by uncommenting
`zip ext in php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install zip
```

I'm running a docker container and this helped me

```
docker-compose exec app apt-get install zip
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

locate php.ini and search 'zip', then uncomment/remove semicolon

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows OS** kindly open this directory (**C:\xampp\php\php.ini** in my case).
It will open in notepad .

Now to save time press **Ctrl+F**, type "**zip**"
NB make sure your Direction option is **Down** now click on **Find Next** you will find it("zip") equated like this **;extension = zip** now remove the **semicolon ";"**  before the word "**extension**" save it and close the file.

Now go back to your **CMD** and run your:
*composer global require laravel/installer* command