# fatal: reference is not a tree on composer install

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

Trying to install packages on composer.json using `composer install` on production and I get this error.

I've tried different solutions which I found from search which includes

- Clearing cache
- running `composer update`
- Delete vendor, clear cache and run `composer install`
- Delete vendor, clear cache and run `composer update`

And none worked.

However, I was able to run `composer install` successfully on local.

How do I fix this? Attached is my screen with the error.

Thank you.

[image: composer error]

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274829/php-error-the-zip-extension-and-unzip-command-are-both-missing-skipping

Comment: I actually did an `apt-get upgrade` and composer is in it's latest version

Comment: Did you install the zip extension and the unzip command?

Comment: I don't have a problem with zip as regards to the link.
My error is different from that of the link.

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your flavour of Linux and PHP version these may vary.

```
(sudo) yum install zip unzip php-zip
```

or

```
(sudo) apt install zip unzip php-zip
```

Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274829/php-error-the-zip-extension-and-unzip-command-are-both-missing-skipping)

Answer (score 1):

composer cannot find some commit from git cache, so order it to get package directly from its repository. this works for me:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
```