# Is there a problem with using php-zip (composer warns about it)?

Tags: php, zip

When using composer install with the `zip` CLI command absent, I get the following warning:

> As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked
>   using the PHP zip extension. This may cause invalid reports of corrupted
>   archives. Installing 'unzip' may remediate them.

What does that mean?

In another project we are making the decision whether to use php-zip or the `zip` CLI command, so it looks now like an argument agains `php-zip` PHP extension.

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/07867724d0b053a1b43241ee983143f5a5156d8b https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7383 https://github.com/composer/composer/blame/d73aef5c8a8cb9f1cb7f707e27cbf45f3411c838/src/Composer/Downloader/ZipDownloader.php#L70