# cant install swagger package using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-package

when i try to install swagger package i got this warrning

> Failed to download swagger-api/swagger-ui from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: D:\xampp\php\php.ini
> Now trying to download from source

and after a while i got this error

> In Process.php line 1204:
> The process "git clone --no-checkout -- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-10\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui && c
> d /D D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-10\vendor\swagger-api\swagger-ui && git remote add composer -- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git && git fe
> tch composer && git remote set-url origin -- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git && git remote set-url composer -- https://github.com/swa
> gger-api/swagger-ui.git" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP error: "The zip extension and unzip command are both missing, skipping."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274829/php-error-the-zip-extension-and-unzip-command-are-both-missing-skipping)

Comment: Please don't use tags that are not connected to the given problem. You haven't shared any code related to Laravel or Swagger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here.

1. `ZIP` extension is missing. (*The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping*)
2. Composer timeout. (*exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.*)

---

**For first error**

1. Open your php.ini file(`D:\xampp\php\php.ini`).
2. Find `;extension=zip` and remove the semicolon at the beginning.
3. Save and restart your XAMPP.

> Install https://www.7-zip.org/ if required

**For the second issue**

```
composer config --global process-timeout 600
```